# Laravel auth returns 419 page expired

Tags: laravel

I decided to implement dynamic caching with service worker in my laravel project and since then, anytime i logout. It returns "419 | page expired". How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default, logout is a POST method and you have to add csrf token to logout form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: I know. That comes by default with laravel auth scaffolding and i already have that in my project. The weird part is that it works well when i disable the service worker but it doesn't when i enable the service worker.